# ACPI error when booting; need type reference

Tags: boot, acpi

Starting casually using Ubuntu 22.04 installed through live usb a few weeks ago.

Not sure at all what to do, machine not booting and displaying ACPI errors shown in picture[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the install with `acpi=off nomodeset`

I was facing exactly the same problem during same installation process, and facing it even now after running the install with added parameters.

So now the system can start up only in the recovery mode :(